# Why my UI views have an iOS 6 look when in Xcode but not when building the app

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a project that I created using Xcode 4 and the iOS 6 UI, when I opened the project with Xcode 5 for first the time I was asked if I wanted to convert the project and I said yes, It did its thing and everything worked fine, when I run the application it looks and feels like iOS 7 (the app is super simple). The issue or what I want to change is the way the UI views look in Xcode (UIBuilder), for instance if I add a new button to my view controller it shows the button with the border around it as in iOS 6, but again, when I run the app the border disappears, it looks like iOS 7 without the border which is what I want but it bothers me to see the border when I'm in Xcode.

Any idea? Is this a normal behavior when moving from one iOS version to another?

Thanks

Comment: When you upgrade the project through the automatic xcode upgrade, it changes only the essentials for running the project with iOS 7, it does not change everything in the project. That needs to be done by you.

Comment: Do you know what the process is to change it? Is there any documentation that I can refer to?

Comment: since there are lots of stuff (depending to your actual project and its size) i recommend you create a new project and port your code to the new project and see if all of your code is still compatible. by changing your deployment target you can get the depreciated method warnings and so on in the old project but starting new is always a good idea.

Comment: Ok, I will create a new project and port my code. Thanks a lot